# Incorrect redirect from Google Sites (with embedded Google Drive files) to Drive UI application

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sites, drive

We have an encryption app integrated to Drive UI. In Drive UI it works well. User right click some file, select our application in the context menu and the file gets encrypted.

From March 10 we are getting new problem. Some of our customers have Google Sites with embedded Google Drive files/folders. If user clicks Google Drive file on Google Sites page, then the user is redirected to our encrytpion app. I noticed that another Drive UI applications have the same problem. For some users our app is launched, for some users it is Kami, Lumin and another apps.

I am sure it is a bug on Google side. Google team, please check.

Comment: Maybe if you can provide step-by-step screenshots or a video demonstrating the error then the community will understand from your perspective. Can you provide that? If you really believe this is a bug, file an [issue here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?).

Comment: Looks the issue is fixed by Google now. The conditions to reproduce were: 1) installed application in Google Drive UI; 2) Google Sites page with embedded Google Drive files/folders. When user clicks on folder it is expected to open the folder. However a Drive UI application was launched.